# When injecting a list of beans, is the order in the list the same as the defined order of the beans

Tags: spring

```
@Service @Order(1)
public class FooService implements IService {..}

@Service @Order(2)
public class BarService implements IService {..}
```

Is it guaranteed that the order in the following list will always be `{FooService, BarService}`:

```
@Inject
private List<IService> services;
```

(same question goes for xml config)

Comment: I just tried tracing this through the Spring source code, but it's pretty scary in there, and I can't follow it far enough. I suspect the answer is "yes", though.

Comment: @skaffman That being the most logical behaviour, and given spring's usual 'policy' on that matter, I also suspect "yes". But I'll try to find a proof :)

Comment: @skaffman - it appears our expectations are wrong ;) (see axtavt's answer and comments below)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I guess no because `@Order` is not a general purpose annotation. From [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html):

> NOTE: Annotation-based ordering is supported for specific kinds of components only, e.g. for annotation-based AspectJ aspects. Spring container strategies, on the other hand, are typically based on the Ordered interface in order to allow for configurable ordering of each instance.

Also there are no occurences of `org.springframework.core.annotation.Order` and `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator` in the source of `beans` and `context` modules.

A simple way to make this behave as expected is:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Collections.sort(services, AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
}
```

Comment: And so, if I instead implement `Ordered`, they will be properly ordered in the list?

Comment: @Bozho: I think `Ordered` can't help too - it looks like `OrderComparator` is used only to order special beans such as post processors.

Comment: Tested it, and the test proved you correct. Accepted the answer, and added a workaround to it (if you don't agree with it feel free to remove it :) ).

Comment: Regarding `AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE`, don't know about older versions, but in spring 3.1.2 the `INSTANCE` constant is only declared in the superclass, so one will actually use the mere `OrderComparator` (which is annotation-unaware) unless creating a new instance: `new AnnotationAwareOrderComparator()`.

Answer (score 4):

Since the release of Spring 4, the use of `@Order` has been expanded to include `@Component`

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is invalid since Spring 4([JIRA ticket](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/10245)).

If you add `@Order(1)`, `@Order(2)` to your bean definitions, they will be injected in a collection ordered according to the value parameter.